# PHP getting full image attribute

Tags: php

I am fetching url like facebook. For all images in that page I get them with

```
$src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
```

it works fine if the foreign site put a full webpath to their images. But sometimes they use relative path only and that returns a broken image.

Since I have the full url, is there a way to check if $src contains `http://` or `https`?

if not then I could do

```
$src = $link . '/' . $src;
```

for those relative images. I tried, they display. But if they already had it, then they will not display as path then contains double url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if(strpos($src,'http://')===0 || strpos($src,'https://')===0){
  // full url provided
}else{
  // add domain here
}
```

note that you'll have to use `===` instead of just `==` to distinguish the return-values `false` (not found) and `0` (found at position 0).

Comment: I'd be inclined to only check for `=== 0`

Comment: @Phil: thanks for that hint - i just changed that a second before :D

Comment: perfect. Thanks. One more question. I am using  if(strpos($src,'http://')===0 || strpos($src,'https://')===0){
  $data[$index]['src']    = $src;
}else{
  $data[$index]['src']    = $link . '/' . $src;
}now sometimes they put a '/' in relative path. So how could I avoid double slashes in new $src?

Comment: @lionel28 `$link . '/' . ltrim($src, '/')`

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use `parse_url` for it

```
<?php
$url = parse_url('https://example.org');

if($url['scheme'] == 'https'){
  // is https;
}
```

?>

thanks

Comment: Note that if the URL is relative, `$url['scheme']` will not exist and the code will raise a "Undefined index" notice. Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) first to ensure that `scheme` does indeed exist.

Comment: @Radu : thanks for comments, can you please deifne me mean of url is relative. thanks again...:-)